# align: moving numbers in equations with bulky objects up automatically

Tags: equations

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate, yet I was unable to find what I am looking for in the existing posts. `align` has the nice feature of moving the equation number down if there is no space in the current line, e.g.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\begin{document}
This is the standard output:
\begin{align}
 \vcenter{\hbox{\tikz[scale=2,remember picture]{%
 \duck[graduate=gray!20!black,tassel=red!70!black];
 \coordinate (B1) at (1,0.1);
 }}}~=~\int\!\mathrm{d}^4x\,
 \int\!\mathrm{d}^4y\,\int\!\mathrm{d}^4z\,
 \frac{1}{(x^2-m^2)\,(y^2-m^2)}
\end{align}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[gray](B1)--++(9.3cm,0);}
I want to move the equation number up, but not by hand:
\begin{align}
 \vcenter{\hbox{\tikz[scale=2,remember picture]{%
 \duck[graduate=gray!20!black,tassel=red!70!black];
 \coordinate (B2) at (1,0.1);
 }}}~=~\int\!\mathrm{d}^4x\,
 \int\!\mathrm{d}^4y\,\int\!\mathrm{d}^4z\,
 \frac{1}{(x^2-m^2)\,(y^2-m^2)}\notag\\[-0.6cm] % <-adjusted by hand
\end{align}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[gray](B2)--++(9.3cm,0);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For those who do not like ducks, think of them as placeholders for, say, Feynman diagrams. (The gray lines are just to guide your eye.) As you can see, the equation number would not fit in the current line, and `align` moves it kindly into the next line. However, the first equation wastes some vertical space. I am of course able to fix this by hand, as illustrated in the second equation, or might also cook up a complicated macro for this. The question is whether there is a simple way to move the number up like in equation (2) without tuning things by hand.

Comment: Is replacing `\\[-0.6cm]` by `\\[-\dimexpr2\ht\strutbox\relax]` considered simple?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik If it works, yes. (What would be even better is if none of this was needed, i.e. if this situation arises in which amsmath moves the number to the next line, and if there is a bulky object, it should do this automatically. But this is clearly not part of the question.)

Comment: From the TeXbook: "Plain TeX defines `\strut` to be an invisible box of width zero that extends just enough above and below the baseline so that you would need no interline glue at all if every line contained a strut." So this should be exactly the dimension you want to raise the equation number. Fair enough, `0.6cm` is `17.07182pt`, and `2\ht\strutbox` is `16.79993pt`, so yes, it works :). But I'll try find a way to patch this into `align` (spoiler alert: I'll fail :P).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I don't think it is necessary to do that. Just post your solution as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `amsmath` to do it will be more difficult and will break more things than just the line :P

Instead of manually adjusting the height, you can use a `\strut`. From the TeXbook:

> Plain TeX defines `\strut` to be an invisible box of width zero that extends just enough above and below the baseline so that you would need no interline glue at all if every line contained a strut.

So this is exactly the amount you want to raise the equation number. You just have to replace the `\\[-0.6cm]` by `\\[-\dimexpr2\ht\strutbox\relax]` (The `\strutbox` is the box that is placed when you place the `\strut`). Notice that you need to return twice the height of the `\strutbox` to counteract the `\\`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
This is the standard output:
\begin{align}
 \vcenter{\hbox{\tikz[scale=2,remember picture]{%
 \duck[graduate=gray!20!black,tassel=red!70!black];
 \coordinate (B1) at (1,0.1);
 }}}~=~\int\!\mathrm{d}^4x\,
 \int\!\mathrm{d}^4y\,\int\!\mathrm{d}^4z\,
 \frac{1}{(x^2-m^2)\,(y^2-m^2)}
\end{align}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[gray](B1)--++(9.3cm,0);}
I want to move the equation number up, but not by hand:
\begin{align}
 \vcenter{\hbox{\tikz[scale=2,remember picture]{%
 \duck[graduate=gray!20!black,tassel=red!70!black];
 \coordinate (B2) at (1,0.1);
 }}}~=~\int\!\mathrm{d}^4x\,
 \int\!\mathrm{d}^4y\,\int\!\mathrm{d}^4z\,
 \frac{1}{(x^2-m^2)\,(y^2-m^2)}\notag\\[-\dimexpr2\ht\strutbox\relax] % <- not anymore!
\end{align}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[gray](B2)--++(9.3cm,0);}
\Large
The font size can even change!
\begin{align}
 \vcenter{\hbox{\tikz[scale=1.5,remember picture]{%
 \duck[graduate=gray!20!black,tassel=red!70!black];
 \coordinate (B3) at (1,0.1);
 }}}~=~\int\!\mathrm{d}^4x\,
 \int\!\mathrm{d}^4y\,\int\!\mathrm{d}^4z\,
 \frac{1}{(x^2-m^2)\,(y^2-m^2)}\notag\\[-\dimexpr2\ht\strutbox\relax] % <- not anymore!
\end{align}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[gray](B3)--++(9.3cm,0);}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! This clearly shows that ducks are very careful creatures that do not like to waste space! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There is `\raisetag` (to be used with care, because it moves up also the following text).

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}
This is the standard output:
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
  \qquad % just to make it bigger and move down the number
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \duck[graduate=gray!20!black,tassel=red!70!black];
    \coordinate (B1) at (1,0.1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \qquad % just to make it bigger and move down the number
\end{gathered}
=\int\! d^4x
 \int\! d^4y
 \int\! d^4z\,
 \frac{1}{(x^2-m^2)\,(y^2-m^2)}
\end{equation}
Some text following
some text following
some text following
some text following
some text following
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
  \qquad % just to make it bigger and move down the number
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \duck[graduate=gray!20!black,tassel=red!70!black];
    \coordinate (B1) at (1,0.1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \qquad % just to make it bigger and move down the number
\end{gathered}
=\int\! d^4x
 \int\! d^4y
 \int\! d^4z\,
 \frac{1}{(x^2-m^2)\,(y^2-m^2)}
\raisetag{\baselineskip}
\end{equation}
Some text following
some text following
some text following
some text following
some text following

\end{document}
```

Note `gathered` instead of the clumsy `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`.

[image]

No `~=~`, please, it's wrong. And, sorry, but I can't stand the upright “d”.

Comment: Very nice!!! As for upright d's, you probably do not have to deal with dimensional regularization, but I do and really really cannot stand something like `\int d^dx`. But probably these are physicist's conventions, the physics package has `\dd`. And if LaTeX were to make the spaces around the = signs automatically larger than around + or -, I would not have to do it by hand. (And even though I think your answer is a bit more elegant than Phelype's, forgive me if I keep accepting his, I'll upvote some other answers... ;)